# How do I get my parent pom to output tar.gz files

Tags: maven, tar

I have a parent pom and children pon and when I run the mvn clean package on the parent pom I am getting .jar file, is there anyway to change this to tar.gz file? For the children files I have created assembly.xml files to specify tar.gz file do I need to do the same for parent pom?

Answer (score 1):

The parent is not really meant to produce artifacts other tan the pom.

You could try attaching the assembly plugin to a phase such as `process-resources` or something and try to have it package whatever resources you have in mind, but... generally, it's not a good idea to keep resources in your parent.

If the projects that extend this parent do not define `<packaging/>`, their packaging will default to `pom`.

Answer (score 1):

Specify POM packaging:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

I'm a little surprised that your parent POM is working without that setting.  I've received errors from Maven before when I create a new parent POM and forget to change the packaging from jar (default) to POM.